# Passar pixeis RGB de um ficheiro para Estrutura em C

Tags: c, rgb, pixels

Boa tarde,
Estou a fazer um projeto na cadeira de Estrutura de Dados e tenho este ficheiro, com vários pixeis RGB. 
Gostaria de ler o ficheiro e passar os valores para uma estrutura, em que ficasse cada pixel com RGB. por exemplo, o primeiro pixel ficar com R=241 ,G=5 ,B= .
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como é que faço isso?

Answer (score 1):

> Como é que faço isso?

1. Para ler linhas do ficheiro: usa `fgets()`
2. Para converter texto das linhas em inteiros: usa `strtoul()`
3. Para atribuir valores a variáveis: usa `=`